# Read form fields in a PDF created by Adobe LiveCycle Designer

Tags: python, pdf

How to get the fields from [this PDF file](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/aia0014.pdf)? It is a dynamic PDF created by Adobe LiveCycle Designer. If you open the link in a web browser, you will probably see a single page starting from 'Please wait...' If you download the file and open it via Adobe Reader (5.0 or higher), you should see all 8 pages.

So, when reading via `PyPDF2`, you get an empty dictionary because it renders the file as a single page like that you see via a web browser.

```
def print_fields(path):
    from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
    reader = PdfFileReader(str(path))
    fields = reader.getFields()
    print(fields)
```

You can use Java-dependent library `tika` to read the contents for all 8 pages. However the results are messy and I am avoiding Java dependency.

```
def read_via_tika(path):
    from tika import parser
    raw = parser.from_file(str(path))
    content = raw['content']
    print(content)
```

So, basically, I can manually `Edit -> Form Options -> Export Data…` in Adobe Actobat DC to get a nice XML. Similarly, I need to get the nice form fields and their values via Python.

Comment: Alternatively, use this [link](https://www.uspto.gov/patent/forms/important-information-completing-application-data-sheet-ads) if the one in the question expired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33293026/5229658), I managed to retrieve the fields using `pdfminer.six`.

Navigate through Catalog > AcroForm > XFA, then `pdfminer.pdftypes.resolve1` the object right after `b'datasets'` element in the list.

Comment: How to navigate through Catalog > AcroForm > XFA in PDFMiner? @Max

Comment: I am getting the following error: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'PSKeyword'

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the following code worked (source: [ankur garg](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-extract-data-from-pdf-forms-using-python-10b5e5f26f70))

```
import PyPDF2 as pypdf
def findInDict(needle, haystack):
    for key in haystack.keys():
        try:
            value=haystack[key]
        except:
            continue
        if key==needle:
            return value
        if isinstance(value,dict):            
            x=findInDict(needle,value)            
            if x is not None:
                return x
pdfobject=open('CTRX_filled.pdf','rb')
pdf=pypdf.PdfFileReader(pdfobject)
xfa=findInDict('/XFA',pdf.resolvedObjects)
xml=xfa[7].getObject().getData()
```